# Java Scheduler Rejecting ArrayList Elements

Tags: java

I have a Scheduler which runs and scans several nodes. The list of nodes comes from an ArrayList Object.  When the Scheduler kicks in,  an extended loop steps through the ArrayList and  hands over each node in the list to the scanner.

The problem is that only the first node is scanned. The rest are just kicked away and not scanned. I have been on this for some days now and need some direction on what am doing wrong.

**This is The Output following each scan:**

INFO: /usr/bin/ssh  oscapscn@Sben1a003 // This is successfull

Sben2a004 /home/oscapscn/openscap.bash // This was spewed out

Thank  You.

```
   /**
     * The run method that executes 
     * the scheduled task
     */ 

    public void run() {
    try { 

        List<String> hostList = new JSONSerializationUtility().convertJSONToJava();
        for(String eachNode: hostList) {
            runSchedTask(eachNode);
        }




  //Method that calls the scanner on each
  //node to be scanned
  //=====================================
  private  void runSchedTask(String nodeName) {

   new ScheduledTaskSvcImpl().performHostScan(nodeName.trim()); 


}
```

Comment: I'd try adding a `try/catch` block to the `for` loop. It's possible an exception is occurring and being swallowed.

Comment: Thanks Chris. There is a try/catch block in place.

Comment: What is going on is that, it takes about 3 minutes to scan each node but it looks like the loop can't wait